# Text Is Not Being Appended and Sent

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, append, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command for my discord bot that receives text, uppercases every other letter, appends it to an array, and sends it back. I have it working so that it can append text and print it back out, but when I try to uppercase it things go awry.

```
@bot.command()
async def spongetext(ctx, *, message):
    textmessage = []
    for letter in message:
        textmessage.append(letter)
    await ctx.send(textmessage)
```

The code above works and outputs the following when it's run as `.spongetext test test`

`['t', 'e', 's', 't', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't']`

However, when I use this code to uppercase every other letter

````
async def spongetext(ctx, *, message):
    textmessage = []
    for letter in message:
        if letter % 2 == 0:
            textmessage.append(letter.upper())
        else:
            textmessage.append(letter)
    await ctx.send(textmessage)```


Nothing is output, no error message, and no text
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code, `if letter % 2 == 0:` makes  no sense, you cant factorial an alphabet.

Try something like this:

```
message = "hello, this is a message."

textmessage = []

for i in range(0,len(message)):
        letter = message[i]
        if i % 2 == 0:
            textmessage.append(letter.upper())
        else:
            textmessage.append(letter)

print(textmessage)
print("".join(textmessage))
```

Answer (score 0):

For your "if" statement, you're comparing the letter itself, performing `% 2 == 0` on it. Instead, you can use enumerate to get the index you're on, as well.

```py
for i, letter in enumerate(message):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        textmessage.append(letter.upper())
    else:
        textmessage.append(letter)
```